# How to load large videos dataset with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, dataset, multiprocess, imread

I am working with a large dataset of videos preprocessed and converted in frames. So I have the following folder tree:

- data

  - training_set

    - class1

      - video1

        - Frame0.png, ..., FrameN.png
      - videoN

        - Frame0.png, ..., FrameN.png
    - class2

      - video1

        - Frame0.png, ..., FrameN.png
      - videoN

        - Frame0.png, ..., FrameN.png
  - validation_set

    - class1

      - video1

        - Frame0.png, ..., FrameN.png
      - videoN

        - Frame0.png, ..., FrameN.png
    - class2

      - video1

        - Frame0.png, ..., FrameN.png
      - videoN

        - Frame0.png, ..., FrameN.png

I need to load all these data and everytime I read a video from the class1 folder I add a 0 to the labels list and everytime I read a video from the class2 folder I add a 1 to the labels.

Since the videos are thousands I wish to multiprocess but I don't understand how to do that maintaining the coherence between videos and labels.

```
sets = [TRAINING_DIR, VALIDATION_DIR]

for dataset in sets:
    for folder in classes:
        subfolder = os.path.join(dataset, folder)
        if max_videos > -1:
            bar_length = min(max_videos, len(os.listdir(subfolder)))
        else:
            bar_length = len(os.listdir(subfolder))

        bar = ChargingBar('Loading ' + subfolder, max=bar_length)
        bar_interval = int(min(max_videos, len(os.listdir(subfolder)))/bar_length)
        if bar_interval == 0:
            bar_interval = 1

        for index, video_folder_name in enumerate(os.listdir(subfolder)):
            if index == max_videos:
                break
            video_path = os.path.join(subfolder, video_folder_name)
            frames_number = len(os.listdir(video_path))
            frames_interval = int(frames_number / min_video_frames)
            frames_paths = os.listdir(video_path)
            if frames_interval > 0:
                frames_paths = frames_paths[::frames_interval]
            frames = []
            for index, frame_image in enumerate(frames_paths):
                if len(frames) >= min_video_frames:
                    break
                image = np.asarray(cv2.imread(os.path.join(video_path, frame_image)))
                image = cv2.resize(image, (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))
                frames.append(image)

            while len(frames) < min_video_frames:
                frames.append(frames[-1])

            if dataset == TRAINING_DIR:
                videos.append(frames)
                if "class1" in folder:
                    labels.append(0)
                else:
                    labels.append(1)
            else:
                validation_videos.append(frames)
                if "class1" in folder:
                    validation_labels.append(0)
                else:
                    validation_labels.append(1)
            
            if index % bar_interval == 0:
                bar.next()
            
        bar.finish()
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. But I see other problem - processes doesn't share memory so they will keeps data in separated memories and to get all in one list/dataframe one process will have to save it on disk and other will have to read it - so it may works slower then in normal way.

Comment: maybe you should keep it as pairs `(frames, label)` on one list `train_data` (and `validation_data`) instead of two lists `videos`, `labels`. Or maybe you should keep it in `DataFrame`

Comment: @furas and how can I deal with more processes editing the same structure?